# Does the continued fractions $3+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{7+\cdots}}$ equal $\pi$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

$3+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{7+\cdots}}=\pi$ Is it true? If yes, how to show it?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect it to? Is this an exercise from some book, and in that case, what sort of level is it?

Comment: I found it on the internet. I think it is not true. Is it?

Comment: In that case, could you provide a link?

Comment: [See this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502233/relation-between-e-and-pi) See the comment to the question.

Comment: Sorry, The new answer tells that I was expecting wrong.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001203 says it's not $3, 5, 7$ but rather $3, 7, 15$ which starts off the continued fraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the continued fraction converged to $\pi$, the value of the  odd convergent 
$$
3 +\cfrac1{
5 +\cfrac1{
7}} = \frac{115}{36} = 3.19444\ldots
$$

would be strictly smaller than $\pi$.  But the convergent is already too big.  The actual value of the continued fraction must exceed $\frac{115}{36}$;  it lies somewhere between 
 $\frac{115}{36} \approx 3.1944$ and $\frac{1051}{329} \approx 3.1945$.

---

Another way to see this is:

1. Simple continued fraction representations of irrational numbers are unique
2. The continued fraction representation of $\pi$ begins $3+\frac1{7+\cdots}$, not $3+\frac1{5+\cdots}$.
3. Therefore, this is not the continued fraction representation of $\pi$.